# ansible run command on remote host in background

Tags: ansible

I am trying to start filebeat (or for that matter any other process which will run continuously on demand) process on multiple hosts using ansible. I don't want ansible to wait till the process keeps on running. I want ansible to fire and forget and come out and keep remote process running in back ground.
I've tried using below options:

```
    ---
    - hosts: filebeat
      tasks:
      - name: start filebeat
option a)  command: filebeat -c filebeat.yml &
option b)  command: nohup filebeat -c filebeat.yml &
option c)  shell: filebeat -c filebeat.yml &
           async: 0 //Tried without as well. If its > 0 then it only waits for that much of time and terminates the filebeat process on remote host and comes out.
           poll: 0
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://superuser.com/questions/870871/run-a-remote-script-application-in-detached-mode-in-ansible

Comment: i've already commented on that post where it is not working for me using daemon command

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Simplified answer from [link](https://superuser.com/questions/870871/run-a-remote-script-application-in-detached-mode-in-ansible) I mentioned in the comment:

```
---
- hosts: centos-target
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - shell: "(cd /; python -mSimpleHTTPServer >/dev/null 2>&1 &)"
      async: 10
      poll: 0
```

Note subshell parentheses.

Update: actually, you should be fine without `async`, just don't forget to redirect stdout:

```
- name: start simple http server in background
  shell: cd /tmp/www; nohup python -mSimpleHTTPServer </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: What are the options 'async' and 'poll'? They are not documented (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/shell_module.html)

Comment: How did you kill the process?

Comment: @dokaspar They are documented in a different place: [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html).

Comment: @dokaspar to elaborate, note that if `async` and `poll` were options on `shell`, they would need to be indented under `shell` (and the string next to `shell:` would have to be part of the `shell:` dictionary as well, it would be indented under `cmd: [the command string]` -- you can use shorthand or dictionary syntax, but not both). `async` and `poll` apply to tasks, similarly to how `name` can apply to tasks, but they're not restricted to being arguments of a _specific_ task

Comment: Using "ansible filebeat-m shell -a 'ps -ef|grep filebeat'" to check if all process is up and it works out,Good solution