# Ansible terminates my app with "nohup"

Tags: java, bash, ansible

I have a task in Ansible playbook that executes a .jar file in the background, but after finishing that task, the (java) app terminates.

```
- name: Run Java app in the background
  shell: nohup java -jar app.jar &
```

I need the app running for tasks further down in the playbook. Any ideas??
NOTE: When I run it in Putty ssh session it runs smoothly and the app stays in background.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347379/ansible-run-command-on-remote-host-in-background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok So I had this issue today and my script is a tad different but essentially doing the same thing so this is what I have, running on Oracle, Centos and RHEL.

in script start_service.sh I have this, this script is executed not sourced.

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd)"
nohup java -jar ${DIR}/$1 --spring.config.location=${DIR}/application.yml --logging.config=${DIR}/logging.xml > ${DIR}/log/output.log 2>&1 &
```

In my playbook I have:

```
- name: run service
  shell: "{{ service_install_location }}/application_name/start-service.sh application_name-{{ application_version }}.jar"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ service_install_location }}/application_name"
    executable: /bin/bash
```

Now, the BASH_SOURCE argument is specific to bash so if you are running plain old sh then you need $0. nohup is required so when the ssh connection terminates your background task does not get killed (turn on -vvv for ansible to see connections being made to understand how this happens on a remote machine).

I should point out we are doing this temporarily as this should really be installed as a service to be under the control of service/init.d but for now, this answers your question

Answer (score 8):

The most likely reason is attached IO. Try:

```
- name: Run Java app in the background
  shell: nohup java -jar app.jar </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: I have tried this, but with no prevail. It terminates the app regardless. I am wondering if every executed task spawns a new ssh session or everything that is run in the playbook is done within one ssh session. That is one thing that I can think of that terminates the app after the session is ended.

Comment: Every task is a new ssh session. You may try other options from my note [here](https://ansibledaily.com/execute-detached-process-with-ansible/).

Comment: "Every task is a new ssh session", thats not always true if running locally :)

Comment: This worked perfectly for me with a `java -jar ...` command. Thank you!