# Execute background process from Ansible

Tags: ssh, background, ansible

Ansible runs processing using SSH.
Therefore, it is not possible to start the background process.

Is there a solution to start background processes with Ansible?
Thank you.

Comment: dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347379/ansible-run-command-on-remote-host-in-background/39355842#39355842

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with ansible. Take a look at  http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_async.html

Comment: `async` is not quite a background task, see link in OP comment