# Can Ansible keep a process ruining even after the playbook has ended?

Tags: deployment, process, ansible, devops

i have an open-source program i want to run from ansible basically ansible will go into the node and run  "./Program.Name" which will start the program but when ansible-playbook is done the program closes is there a way I can start the program and keep it running even after ansible is done? I was told there is the async module but how can I write the playbook so it will keep the program running for as long as the node is up. Please try to provide the yml code if possible where I can replace the name of the program and it should do the job

I have tried to run the porcess with "./Program.Name &"  but it does not stay running.

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347379/ansible-run-command-on-remote-host-in-background ?

Comment: May need to add `nohup` to your shell command. For example `nohup ./Program.Name >/dev/null 2>&1 &`. This will stop the process being killed when the user disconnects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following methods may be useful to you, and the `async` and `poll` parameters are necessary,more info see [ansible doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_async.html)

```
- name: run
  shell: "( tail > /dev/null 2>&1 &)"
  async: 10
  poll: 0
```

Note: If you want to run the program with a daemon, I think `supervisord` may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

async poll = 0

just never check back in on the task

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html#concurrent-tasks-poll-0