# To stop the script when you run another script

Tags: python-3.x

I have several python scripts. 
In the first script, when certain conditions are met, the second script starts:

```
count += 1
if count == 3:
    fin = Popen("python3 autoclear.py", shell=True)
```

How can I make it so that when a new script is launched according to the condition, the original script stops working?

The solutions I found before interrupted python completely (completing the interpreter), not a specific script.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to start a new Python interpreter?

You could put the two scripts in a package, put what is done in autoclear in a function and call this function in your main file.

Structure

```
current_folder
script.py
/script_package
   __init__.py
   autoclear.py
```

in `autoclear.py`

```py
def autoclear():
    # put everything in this function
```

in `script.py`

```py
from script_package.autoclear import autolclear

count += 1
if count == 3:
    fin = autoclear()
```

---

**Edit**

Answer to the comment, if you really need to do it, I think calling the Python process in background should work:

```py
count += 1
if count == 3:
    fin = Popen("python3 autoclear.py &", shell=True)
```

---

**Edit2**:
you can try with ansible, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39355842/11832127) could help.

Comment: The fact is that I would like it to remain as different scripts in principle. 
Is it possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution did not help. The first script is still executed simultaneously with the second. @ndclt

Comment: An other edit, with another solution. :-) I hope it will work

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help either. I can't figure out what the problem might be. The second script is still called and runs simultaneously with the first one. Already I think just to put on the first `time.delay(99999999999999)`, so that he quietly let the second one do the work, but I think this is a terrible decision.