# Unable to run npm start command

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-ec2, ansible

Hi I am trying to run npm start command but I am unable to do so, ansible runs npm install command and when I go inside the ec2 instance I am able to see the node modules but the application is not running

```
- name: MongoDB Deployment
  hosts: db
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
  tasks: 
    - name: Copy and Execute the script 
      become: true 
      script: ./scripts/mongodb.sh
- name: Deploy Application
  hosts: web
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
  tasks: 
    - name: Copying the Directory's contents (sub directories/files)
      become: true 
      copy:
        src: ../src/
        dest: /code
        owner: ec2-user
        group: ec2-user        
        mode: 0644

    - name: Pause for 1 minutes to connect to mongo db
      pause:
        minutes: 1
    - name: Node module installation
      shell: cd /code && npm install

    - name: Launch Application
      shell: cd /code; nohup npm run start </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

These are the logs I get after running the ansible playbook command.

```
changed: [10.0.14.217] => {
    "changed": true, 
    "cmd": "cd /code; nohup npm run start </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &", 
    "delta": "0:00:00.038954", 
    "end": "2022-05-21 22:38:12.220881", 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "cd /code; nohup npm run start </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &", 
            "_uses_shell": true, 
            "argv": null, 
            "chdir": null, 
            "creates": null, 
            "executable": null, 
            "removes": null, 
            "stdin": null, 
            "stdin_add_newline": true, 
            "strip_empty_ends": true, 
            "warn": true
        }
    }, 
    "rc": 0, 
    "start": "2022-05-21 22:38:12.181927", 
    "stderr": "", 
    "stderr_lines": [], 
    "stdout": "", 
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with ansible, but are you sure youre not already in the `code` directory after you `cd` into it for `npm install`? also unsure of why you are wanting to run it in the background with the `&`? if these are just ansible things then please ignore me

Comment: You cannot run a command in background like this. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39355842/6309601

Comment: I have tried running this way, it shows fine in the logs but the application is not deployed

Comment: I have updated the question with the logs as well

Comment: Not an answer but trying to help troubleshoot. The return code you're getting ("rc": "0") is from the `nohup` command and not from the `npm run start`. Instead of discarding the output of the `npm run start` to `/dev/null`, send it to a file and see what it contains. Let us know what's in there. For example: `shell: cd /code && nohup npm run start </dev/null >/tmp/output.log 2>&1 &`